# Dependencies Anaconda, Spyder, pyqt5

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

since I had problems with the Qt creator I started installing/uninstalling Anaconda and Qt creator several times (I´m not very experienced in programming, and less with Qt, so I`m sure that was probably not the correct attempt).

Now I got problems with Anaconda, that I didn´t have before. Somehow, there was a kind of dependency created by the Qt creator, because many actions in Anaconda seems to rely on PyQt5 now, even after uninstalling Qt Creator and clearing registry, restart after uninstall, etc.. I got the Anaconda-navigator running now after installing pyqt5 by the anaconda prompt. Before I couldn´t launch the navigator anymore. But I still cant start Spyder etc. anymore. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Programme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Programme\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "E:\Programme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 233, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "E:\Programme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 59, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "E:\Programme\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

Why is Anaconda now starting Qt stuff everytime? Where is this directed?

Please help..

Comment: How are you starting spyder here? What did you do to get your anaconda navigator working again?

Comment: "I got the Anaconda-navigator running now after installing pyqt5 by the anaconda prompt. Before I couldn´t launch the navigator anymore. But I still cant start Spyder etc. anymore. I get this error:"

Comment: And the error message you have shown here is from when you try to start `spyder` from anaconda command prompt, i.e. `base` env is activated correctly? If that is the case, I would suggest to run `conda uninstall spyder` followed by `conda install spyder` just to get the dependencies set up correctly again

Comment: By the way, QT is a dependency of both spyder and anaconda navigator. That dependency was not put in place by the qtcreator

Comment: I finally got everything running again via the anaconda prompt. I uninstalled and installed pyqt and pyqt5 modules, but older versions of pyqt5 (5.12.3). This works for me now. But I don't really know why. But I know now, that my Spyder version (5.1.5 is the newest I can install in Anaconda yet) is only compatible with pyqt5 5.12.3 and nothing higher.